# Can chemicals change crystal structure by only touching?

Tags: physical-chemistry, crystal-structure

Are there any known, or suspected compounds that take the crystal structure of what ever object they are touching, i.e. if it touches $\ce{NaCl}$ it would turn into a face centered cubic crystal structure.

Comment: What do you mean by touching? Rubbing to crystals and wow now they have the same structure?

Comment: @Mithoron sort of, but like a liquid crystal, more like: Oops spilled this, OMG its now a the structure of that randomly placed salt on the floor

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no "exact mimic" crystal, but the **[crystal habit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_habit) can alter the crystal form**. Consider that the environment in the uniform inside of a substance is different from that along its boundaries; growing on a different surface can alter the shape of the crystal.

The semiconductor industry, in particular, is often faced with difficulties in growing crystalline semiconductors with layers of varying composition ([epitaxy](http://users.wfu.edu/ucerkb/Nan242/L12-Epitaxy.pdf)). There is often strain, leading to defects, unless an intermediate layer can smooth the transition.